# Add an entry to autocorrect list

Tags: libreoffice-basic

I have a list of incorrect words those needs to be changed to the first one from the comma separated string.
For e.g.

```
teest: test, tested
abut: about, similar
normol: normal, abnormal
```

If there are 2 or 3 words, I can add them to autocorrect list manually.
But there are a lot of such words. I guess a macro can do this.

I can save the list as a dictionary in python. But not sure how to write in basic.

```
import io
import os
import zipfile
import tempfile

# https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=38710

mypath = '/home/ubuntu/.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/lu282754f7as.tmp_/with_acor_N_9_0.oxt/autocorr/'

uid =  os.stat(mypath).st_uid
gid = os.stat(mypath).st_gid

def updateZip(zipname, filename, data):
    # generate a temp file
    tmpfd, tmpname = tempfile.mkstemp(dir=os.path.dirname(zipname))
    os.close(tmpfd)

    # read data from file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipname) as zf:
        with io.TextIOWrapper(zf.open(filename), encoding='utf-8') as f:
            data = f.read() + data

    # create a temp copy of the archive without filename
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, 'r') as zin:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(tmpname, 'w') as zout:
            zout.comment = zin.comment  # preserve the comment
            for item in zin.infolist():
                if item.filename != filename:
                    zout.writestr(item, zin.read(item.filename))

    # replace with the temp archive
    os.remove(zipname)
    os.rename(tmpname, zipname)

    # now add filename with its new data
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zipname, mode='a', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        zf.writestr(filename, data)

mydic = dict()
update = """पररयतन: प्रयत्न, करणे
परररयतन: प्रयत्न, करणे
परररययतन: प्रयत्न, करणे"""

for i in update.split('\n'):
    first = i.split(':')[0]
    mydic[first] = i.split(':')[1].split(',')[0].strip()

for i in mydic:
    mystr = '<block-list:block block-list:abbreviated-name="'+i+'" block-list:name="'+mydic[i]+'"/>\n'
    updateZip(mypath+'acor_mr-IN.dat', 'DocumentList.xml', mystr)

os.chown(mypath+'acor_mr-IN.dat', uid, gid)
```

The .dat file is compressed. It needs to be unzipped first before adding text. Is it possible in basic?

---

Update:

The incorrect and correct words ("Teest" , "Test") should be passed as a parameter. And they should be picked from the current open document. This is correctly done in the python code mentioned above.

```
Sub Test() 
  Dim oPathSettings As Object, oPackage As Object, oDom As Object, oNode As Object
  Dim oPackageFolder As Object, oPackageStream As Object, oOutputStream As Object, oTempFile As Object
  Dim filePath As String, DocumentList As String, arr
  oPathSettings = GetDefaultContext.getValueByName("/singletons/com.sun.star.util.thePathSettings")

  dim oProvider as object
  oProvider=GetDefaultContext.getByName("/singletons/com.sun.star.deployment.PackageInformationProvider")
  filePath=oProvider.getPackageLocation("org.openoffice.mr.dictionaries.mr") & "/autocorr/acor_mr-IN.dat"
    
  oPackage=createUnoService("com.sun.star.packages.Package")
  oPackage.initialize Array(filePath)
  
  DocumentList="DocumentList.xml"
  oPackageStream=oPackage.getByHierarchicalName(DocumentList)
  oDom=createUnoService("com.sun.star.xml.dom.DocumentBuilder").parse(oPackageStream.inputStream)
  
  oNode=oDom.documentElement.appendChild(oDom.createElement("block-list:block"))
  oNode.setAttribute("block-list:abbreviated-name", "Teest")
  oNode.setAttribute("block-list:name", "Test")
  
  oTempFile=createUnoService("com.sun.star.io.TempFile")
  oDom.setOutputStream oTempFile.OutputStream
  oDom.start
  oTempFile.OutputStream.closeOutput
   
  oPackageFolder=oPackage.getByHierarchicalName("")
  oPackageFolder.removeByName DocumentList  
  oPackageStream=oPackage.createInstanceWithArguments(Array(False))
  oPackageStream.SetInputStream(oTempFile.InputStream)
  oPackageFolder.insertByName(DocumentList, oPackageStream)
  
  oPackage.commitChanges 
End Sub
```